# Can anyone point out why I've got this error 'malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion'?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I've heard this memory related error is one of the nastiest memory error.
I'm sure it's related to the memory allocated to some struct I've declared.
The following is the struct I'm using.

```
struct bitmap
{
    ST_INT* ps32bitmaparr;
    ST_INT* ps32bitposarr;
};
typedef struct bitmap BITMAP;

BITMAP* gpbitmap;
```

I've allocated a memory for the struct in a function. I've set the pointer of the struct to global pointer called 'gpbitmap'.

```
pbitmap = safe_malloc(sizeof(BITMAP));
if(s32tot != 0)
{
    ps32bitmaparr = safe_malloc(sizeof(ST_INT)*s32tot+1);
    ps32bitposarr = safe_malloc(sizeof(ST_INT)*s32tot+1);   
}
```

Then, I've freed the memory as the following.

```
if(gpbitmap != NULL)
{
    sxd_process_arb_data(DataEntry->dataBuf, rt_array, rtlen, NULL, &mlog_arb_log_ctrl, NULL);      
    free(gpbitmap->ps32bitmaparr);
    free(gpbitmap->ps32bitposarr);
    free(gpbitmap);
}
```

Then, I've got this error.

```
malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

Since I'm working on the embedded system, I don't exactly know how to use valgrind on this system. Thus, anyone who can spot any possible errors would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are you using malloc on an embedded system? Have you checked if you have a `.heap` segment?

Comment: Your second code snippet store the pointer in local/global variables. Do you actually assign those pointers to `gpbitmap->p32bitmaparr` and the other field?